# how does a while read loop work in bash?

Tags: bash, web-crawler

[This is a crawler from GitHub](https://github.com/ashishvshenoy/Simple_Bash_Crawler) that I am to implement on myself but am unable to read the bash since am a novice. Can this be explained in answer

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create an array files that contains list of filenames
files=($(< url.txt))
cities=($(< city.txt))
url="http://www.grotal.com/"
citycodes=($(<citycode.txt))

# Read through the url.txt file and execute wget command for every filename
while IFS='=| ' read -r param uri; do
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
        for city in "${cities[@]}"; do
            mkdir "${city}"
            mkdir "${city}/${file}"
            wget -O "${city}/${file}/${file}${citycodes[@]}" "${uri}${url}${city}/${file}-${citycodes[@]}/"
        done
    done
done < url.txt
```

specifically these (even if u choose to downvote...)

```
while IFS='=| ' read -r param uri;
```

and then this:

```
done < url.txt
```

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), which describes `while read` loops in detail.

Comment: Also, the way the `files` and `cities` arrays are being populated is extremely buggy. `mapfile -t` or `readarray -t` or `read -r -a` would be far better.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you *only* asked "how does a while read loop work in bash?", that would be a much better question. Including the loop body content, prior setup content, &c. broadens the scope of the question to a point where its topicality here is... questionable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, particularly the parts about what constitutes a good title (needs to be specific to the individual question!)

Comment: ...on the subject of "please explain this code to me" questions, and why it's accepted practice to close them as too broad: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thnx...  i was struggling with `while read`... the link should help...

Comment: (to be clear: `readarray -t files <url.txt`, if on bash 4.0 or newer; or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a files <url.txt || (( ${#files[@]} ))` for compatibility with older bash, will avoid expanding wildcards or splitting on characters in IFS while reading url.txt).

Comment: See: http://explainshell.com/

Comment: Much better, btw; the title update to bring the question's scope in line is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down into pieces:

- `read`, unless given a non-default `-d` argument to specify a terminator to use in place of the newline, reads a single line from stdin (that is, reads up to the next newline); splits that line on IFS characters, and writes each field into a different variable. If it stops being able to read more data before reaching a newline, then it emits a nonzero exit status, *even if it successfully populated the variables given*. (The `-r` argument prevents `read` from treating backslashes as continuation characters rather than literals; unless you have a specific reason to have continuation characters available in the context at hand, you should make a habit of passing `-r` to `read` by default).
- `< url.txt` redirects a read handle on `url.txt` into stdin for the command (including a compound command such as a `while` loop) to which it's appended.
- A `while` loop runs the conditional command it's given, checks whether that conditional reports success or failure, and then proceeds to run the body and restart on success, or exit on failure.

Thus, if you have `IFS='=| ' read -r param uri`, it will read a single line from stdin; assign everything up to the first `=`, `|` or space to the variable named `param`, and assign what's left to the variable `uri`.

If you put that in the conditional part of a `while` loop, then the loop will operate until that `read` fails -- as it will if there isn't more content (up to and including a newline character) available to be read.

For more in-depth discussion of the idiom and its uses, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

---

Some asides:

- Using `mkdir -p -- "${city}/${file}"` will let you have only a single `mkdir` command that creates both directories (and avoids generating error messages if they already exist).
- Using `readarray -t files < url.txt` is a more robust way to read the contents of `url.txt` into an array named `files`, though it requires bash 4.0 or newer. For older versions of the shell, consider `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a files <url.txt || (( ${#files[@]} ))`. These will behave far better than the original idiom if you have wildcards, whitespace, or other unexpected content in your input files.